# Animate toast using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do a stripped down version of googles toast from their material ui collection.

I've narrowed everything down to this.

How can I slide in and slide out the toast vertically using only plain javascript?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.trigger').click(function(){
    if ( $('.Mh0NNb').css('visibility') == 'hidden' )
      $('.Mh0NNb').css('visibility','visible');
    else
      $('.Mh0NNb').css('visibility','hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.Mh0NNb {
    background-color: #323232;
    bottom: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12),0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 14px;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 48px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(0,100%);
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.M6tHv {
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    min-height: inherit;
    padding: 0
}

.aGJE1b {
    box-flex: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    line-height: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 14px 24px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    word-break: break-word
}

.x95qze {
    align-self: center;
    color: #eeff41;
    box-flex: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    float: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    padding: 14px 24px
}

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) {
    .Mh0NNb {
        min-width:288px;
        max-width: 568px;
        border-radius: 2px
    }

    .Mp2Z0b {
        left: 24px;
        margin-right: 24px;
        right: auto
    }

    .VcC8Fc {
        left: 50%;
        right: auto;
        transform: translate(-50%,100%)
    }

    .Mp2Z0b.misTTe {
        bottom: 24px
    }

    .VcC8Fc.misTTe {
        bottom: 0;
        transform: translate(-50%,0)
    }

    .M6tHv {
        padding: 0
    }

    .aGJE1b {
        padding-right: 24px
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .xbgI6e .aGJE1b,.xbgI6e .x95qze {
        padding-bottom:24px;
        padding-top: 24px
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width:568px) {
    .Mh0NNb {
        max-width:90%
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 569px) {
    .Mh0NNb {
        max-width:568px
    }
}

.Mh0NNb.Mh0NNb {
    background-color: #202124;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0
}

.aGJE1b.aGJE1b {
    color: #bdc1c6;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.4
}

.x95qze.x95qze {
    color: #669df6;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-family: 'Google Sans',Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Mh0NNb VcC8Fc misTTe">
    <div class="M6tHv">
        <div class="aGJE1b">Contact details updated</div>
        <div class="dnmu6e" tabindex="0"></div>
        <div class="x95qze" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="J9Hpafc51">Undo</div>
        <div class="dnmu6e" tabindex="0"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="trigger">Toggle Info Box!</button>
```

Comment: By *plain* JS you mean without jQuery?

Comment: Yes, without jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the JS part, toggle (or add / remove) a CSS class.

Then, use the CSS `transform` and `opacity` properties to create a sliding + fading effect, and use `transition` to make them animated:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {  
  document.querySelector('.trigger').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('.Mh0NNb').classList.toggle('active')
  })
})
```

```css
.Mh0NNb {
    background-color: #323232;
    bottom: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12),0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 14px;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 48px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(0,100%);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
    transition: 0.5s transform, 1s opacity;
}
.Mh0NNb.active {
    transform: translate(0,0);
    opacity: 1;
}
.M6tHv {
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    min-height: inherit;
    padding: 0
}

.aGJE1b {
    box-flex: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    line-height: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 14px 24px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    word-break: break-word
}

.x95qze {
    align-self: center;
    color: #eeff41;
    box-flex: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    float: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    padding: 14px 24px
}

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) {
    .Mh0NNb {
        min-width:288px;
        max-width: 568px;
        border-radius: 2px
    }

    .Mp2Z0b {
        left: 24px;
        margin-right: 24px;
        right: auto
    }

    .VcC8Fc {
        left: 50%;
        right: auto;
        transform: translate(-50%,100%)
    }

    .Mp2Z0b.misTTe {
        bottom: 24px
    }

    .VcC8Fc.misTTe {
        bottom: 0;
        transform: translate(-50%,100%)
    }
    .VcC8Fc.active {
        transform: translate(-50%,0);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .M6tHv {
        padding: 0
    }

    .aGJE1b {
        padding-right: 24px
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .xbgI6e .aGJE1b,.xbgI6e .x95qze {
        padding-bottom:24px;
        padding-top: 24px
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width:568px) {
    .Mh0NNb {
        max-width:90%
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 569px) {
    .Mh0NNb {
        max-width:568px
    }
}

.Mh0NNb.Mh0NNb {
    background-color: #202124;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0
}

.aGJE1b.aGJE1b {
    color: #bdc1c6;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.4
}

.x95qze.x95qze {
    color: #669df6;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-family: 'Google Sans',Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}
```

```html
<div class="Mh0NNb VcC8Fc misTTe">
    <div class="M6tHv">
        <div class="aGJE1b">Contact details updated</div>
        <div class="dnmu6e" tabindex="0"></div>
        <div class="x95qze" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="J9Hpafc51">Undo</div>
        <div class="dnmu6e" tabindex="0"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="trigger">Toggle Info Box!</button>
```

Comment: Your answer fades the div in and out. Can it do something like the toasts on this page `https://www.cssscript.com/demo/google-toast-snackbar-material/`

Comment: It works fine on mobile... I'm going to make it work for computers as well

Comment: I've edited my post. I fixed the issue by adding a `transform` declaration to the first media query as well.

Answer (score 1):

Toggle a class to switch CSS animated styles:

- Bind the click event to the button call handler `function toasted()` when triggered:

  ```
  document.querySelector('.arrow').onclick = toasted;
  ```
- The handler must pass the event object then determine what the user clicked by using `e.target` property.

  ```
  function toasted(e) {
    let clicked = e.target;
    if (clicked.matches('.arrow')) {//...
  ```
- Once it's established that the button was clicked toggle the class `.show` on the button (optional) and the toast (required).

  ```
  //...
    /*
    toast follows button use .nextElementSibling property
    button follows toast use .previousElementSibling property
    */ 
    let toast = clicked.nextElementSibling; 
    toast.classList.toggle('show');
    clicked.classList.toggle('show');
    //...
  ```

The animation is simple CSS:

- Establish the selectors at original state (ie hidden)

  ```
  .toast {
    ...
    transform: translateX(0%);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s
  }
  ```

  `transform: translateX(0%)` means slide left/right of 0 distance.
  `opacity: 0` means it's there but not visible.
  `transition: 0.5s` means if and when those 2 properties change values, make it so it takes half a second. That's what drives the animation. Otherwise the changes would be instant.
- The next CSS ruleset is for the new state when the `.show` class is added:

  ```
  .toast.show {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  ```

  `transform: translateX(100%);` means move toast 100% of its own length from left to right. If you want right to left then `translateX(100%)`, top to bottom `translateY(100%)`, bottom to top `translateY(-100%)`.
  `opacity: 1` no brainer.

---

#### Demo

```js
document.querySelector('.arrow').onclick = toasted;

function toasted(e) {
  let clicked = e.target;
  if (clicked.matches('.arrow')) {
    let toast = clicked.nextElementSibling;
    toast.classList.toggle('show');
    clicked.classList.toggle('show');
  }
}
```

```css
.arrow {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.arrow.show {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.toast {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(0%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.toast.show {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button class='arrow'>◀</button>
<p class='toast'>HEY!</p>
```